# Conditional Statements not working in React-Native On Change Event

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to React-native so pardon me for any childish mistake.
I am a creating a form for user profile but facing a problem with  conditional statement.Have a look at this `

```
  onPress: function () {
      var value = this.refs.form.getValue();
      var result = Validate.formSubmit();
      if(result.status === "error"){
        ToastAndroid.show('error',0)
      }else {
        ToastAndroid.show('Successfully Saved',0)
      }
    }`
```

( onPress is the event Handler of form submit ) In all the cases , whether `result.status` is true or false both the statements get execute .
Also this console statement also get execute

```
if(false){
  console.log('this is under falsy condition');
 }
```

Comment: result.status .?
you cannot do that, try accessing from the state like "this.state.result.status" or pass result to function(result), its scope issue.

Comment: I have  made some changes in the code.Please go through the code again

Comment: What returns `formSubmit()` method?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are calling this function in the render method?

Comment: form submit return an object having 'states = error' or 'states = ok
'

Comment: problem solved.Thanks for help .T'was the browser problem , in the chromium debugging tools the control run through each and every line irrespective of the statement behavior.But console.log cleared everything.